# For which values of complex numbers z is the following series convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, exponential-function

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{nz}$$

I’ve tried to use the geometric series and the fact that z=x+iy to determine the values for z but I couldn’t restrict z by doing this.
Am I doing this wrong or how else should I do this?

Comment: Hint: $|e^{nz}|=e^{nx}$.

Answer (score 3):

Since $e^{nz}=(e^z)^n$, your series *is* a geometric series. It converges if and only if $|e^z|<1$, which is the same thing as saying that $\operatorname{Re}z<0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\left|\sum_ne^{nz}\right|=\left|\sum_ne^{nx}\text{cis}(ny)\right|\le \sum_ne^{nx}$$ and the RHS converges for $x<0$. For $x\ge0$, the general term $e^{nz}$ does not tend to zero.